# Conditionally disable Serilog Sinks individually

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I have serilog on my .net core app basic config as follows:-

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.File(@"./logs/log-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE)
        .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
        .WriteTo.SomeOtherLog()
        .CreateLogger();
```

Lets now say I wish to write to SomeOtherLog based on a condition.  How would one go about that?

Something like

```
if(conditon)
.WriteTo.SomeOtherLog()
```

Comment: Check this answer: **[Is it possible to elegantly configure Serilog with if-statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52998893/211672)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
var configuration = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.File(@"./logs/log-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                      outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE)
        .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate);

if (condition)
{
    configuration.WriteTo.SomeOtherLog();
}

Log.Logger = configuration.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Great, question what could be this condition? Because I can see that the condition IF is inside the setup, what about if inside my c# controller I need to do that condition to choose what SINK to use?  Question, my Serilog configuration is in my appsettings.json, can I still do that conditional and how? Appreciate it

Answer (score 11):

As of [Serilog 2.9.0](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/releases/tag/v2.9.0) you can now use `.WriteTo.Conditional` and specify the condition that defines if the sink will be written to or not.

```
Log.Information("Hello");
Log.CloseAndFlush();

var configuration = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.File(@"./logs/log-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE)
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
    .WriteTo.Conditional(evt => condition, wt => wt.SomeOtherLog());

Log.Logger = configuration.CreateLogger();
// ...
```

Comment: Augusto .. is `evt => condition` evaluated only at 'creation'?..  or if the condition changes at runtime, that '.WriteTo.' will be toggled on/off?  I was searching for documentation to `.WriteTo.Conditional(...)` but could not find any; could you amend the answer above to show a working `evt => condition, wt => wt.SomeOtherLog()`

Comment: @George2.0Hope I had the same question about condition changing at runtime. I tested changing condition at runtime and '.WriteTo' is toggled.