# Serilog Range level filtering

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, serilog

In log4net you have the option to declare different fileappenders with a levelMin levelMax range.
In that way you can have one file for debug and one file for error.
How can I have the same behavior in serilog file sink.
I have this code but you are only allowed to specify MinimumLevel

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Async(a =>
            {
                a.RollingFile($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\Logs\\error.txt", 
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error);
            })
            .WriteTo.Async(a =>
            {
                a.RollingFile($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\Logs\\log.txt",
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug);
            })
            .CreateLogger();
```

It creates two files but in the log.txt I also see the error level messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Serilog you can do use [sub-loggers](http://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/) with a filter applied to each of them:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Logger(c =>
        c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
            .WriteTo.File("Debug.log"))
    .WriteTo.Logger(c =>
        c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
            .WriteTo.File("Error.log"))
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Debug("This goes to Debug.log only");
Log.Error("This goes to Error.log only");

Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) if you just want to map a `LogEventLevel` to a file.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Map(evt => evt.Level, (level, wt) => wt.File($"{level}.log"))
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Debug("This goes to Debug.log only");
Log.Error("This goes to Error.log only");

Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

Comment: that does not work. Information is not logged anywhere.

Comment: @pantonis If you run this on a Console app, it should create two `.log` files with the information...

Comment: I used the first approach and I dont see Information Level logged in any of the files

Comment: I had to add an or condition in the debug level ```e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug || e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information```

Comment: do filters affect performance? I am writing a real time critical info and I want to be sure that serilog filtering does not cause any performance degradations

Comment: @pantonis The code above was a sample code to demonstrate how filter works, so yes... You have to adapt it to match your needs.

Comment: @pantonis The performance hit of adding filters on the event log level is minimal, but you should measure it to see if it's acceptable to you.