# Serilog - Separate files for Information, exception using appsetting.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog, serilog-exceptions

I am writing all logs into one file(s) using rolling. But I want to separate them by `Information`, `Warning` and `Exceptions` rolling files.

my current configuration is like this

```
     "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "pathFormat": "logs\\log-{Hour}.log",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit ": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit ": null,
          "rollingInterval": "Hour",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 5000000
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

**class**

```
public ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        _logger =
            new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

        return _logger ;
    }
```

Comment: to close the question, could you validate one of the answers?

Answer (score 5):

In Serilog you could do this separation either via [sub-loggers](http://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/) or via [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map).

You wouldn't be able to configure the whole pipeline via `appsetting.json` but you can easily configure the path of each file in `appsetting.json` using a custom key of your choice, and use that when configuring the log pipeline via code.

---

Example using [sub-loggers](http://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/) with a filter applied to each of them:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Logger(c =>
        c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
            .WriteTo.File("Debug.log"))
    .WriteTo.Logger(c =>
        c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
            .WriteTo.File("Error.log"))
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Debug("This goes to Debug.log only");
Log.Error("This goes to Error.log only");

Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

---

Example using [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) mapping each `LogEventLevel` to a different file.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Map(evt => evt.Level, (level, wt) => wt.File($"{level}.log"))
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Debug("This goes to Debug.log only");
Log.Error("This goes to Error.log only");

Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

Comment: I wonder if there are significant difference in performance between those two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

i have not tested but by extrapoling the documentation: you could try to create 2 sections in you appconf file

```
  "ErrorLog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "pathFormat": "logs\\ Errorlog-{Hour}.log",       
          "rollingInterval": "Hour",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "InfoLog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "pathFormat": "logs\\ Infolog-{Hour}.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Hour",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

and you create 2 loggers:

```
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();


        var errorSection = configuration.GetSection("ErrorLog");
        var infoSection = configuration.GetSection("InfoLog");


        _errorlog = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom
            .ConfigurationSection(errorSection)
            .CreateLogger();

        _infolog = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom
            .ConfigurationSection(infoSection)
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: can you give the link to documentation?

Comment: @James123 it is not documentation, it is just seperate loggers. One for each severity level.

Comment: @James123, i have just extrapoled, the documentation shows sample with only one logger. (sorry for my english). And i use a similary program. I am not up to date with the version of serilog, but i dont think its a problem